# Executable Jar with Eclipse & Libgdx

Tags: java, eclipse, desktop-application, libgdx

This is the first time I have tried to create an executable jar file from Eclipse, and I am confused as to how to do so. I know that there is the option to export a java file as a "jar" and "executable jar", but I am not sure how to ensure that my libgdx libraries, assets, and HighScore.txt file are fully integrated and are working. Furthermore, like most packages my package has a myriad of classes - one of which is the main class. How do I export the jar files and instruct eclipse that this specific class is the main class.
Here is an image of my file structure:

[image: File Structure in Eclipse]

`MainSimpleBike` is my main class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Using the default jar

   You specify your main class during runtime, like:

   ```
   java -jar MyJar.jar MainSimpleBike
   ```
2. You may also modify the manifest.txt by following the instruction here:

   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

   If you modify the manifest.txt, like:

   ```
   Main-Class: com.me.mygdxgame.MainSimpleBike
   ```

   To create a jar:

   ```
   jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt com.me.mygdxgame/*.class
   ```

   You can simply run:

   ```
   java -jar MyJar.jar
   ```

   Your main class will be picked up automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an executable .jar file for Libgdx desktop apps from within Eclipse.  (@Mingyu's answer is correct, but requires manually creating the Manifest and doesn't take advantage of Eclipse's infrastructure.)

First, you need to make a "Launch Configuration" (this is needed to run your desktop app from Eclipse anyway).

- On the `Run` menu select `Run Configurations ...`,
- pick the `Java Application` entry on the left, and click the "New"
  button to make a new configuration.
- On the right you'll pick the main class, the JRE, the classpath, etc.

For more details see the  [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm)

Now that you've told Eclipse how to run your Desktop Libgdx app, you just need to package that up into an executable Jar.

- Right-click on your desktop project and select `Export...`.
- Choose `Runnable JAR file` (do *not* choose the `JAR file` entry).
- Click `Next` and now pick the launch configuration you just made, and
  where to save the .jar.

For Libgdx I've found that the "Package requires libraries into generated JAR" option generates a working JAR file.

Comment: Added bullet formatting to make it clearer. +1 for exporting runnable JAR!

Answer (score 2):

Run `gradlew desktop:dist` from the command line in the root of your project.  This will create a runnable jar file in .\desktop\builds\libs.